# Fiction "Division by Zero" By Ted Chiang

Tags: meta-math

Fiction "Division by Zero" By Ted Chiang

I read the fiction story ["Division by Zero" By Ted Chiang](http://www.fantasticmetropolis.com/i/division/full/)

My interpretation is the character finds a proof that arithmetic is inconsistent.

Is there a formal proof the fiction can't come true? (I don't suggest the fiction can come true).

EDIT: I see someone [tried](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/40920)

Comment: +1 for interesting question. I'll have to finish reading it first. But I do find a bit to quibble with in the first paragraph: usually $0\times \infty$ is regarded as an indeterminate form, not 0.

Comment: [This](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/40920) might be interesting to you...

Comment: Ted Chiang resources: http://www.freesfonline.de/authors/Ted_Chiang.html

Comment: As with all stories, it's about people, emotions etc. Any math it borrows is just a prop, and doesn't have to be correct. As with many stories, there is a kind of superficial profoundness. You may as well ask if there's a proof that Gandalf can't come back from the dead as Gandalf the Green, Gandalf the Tartan etc - there is no formal proof of any such thing, but it's still not going to happen in reality.

Comment: Possibly worth saying, though - there are some people who claim it's possible to taking a ratio of the largest useful number to the smallest useful number based on physics and astronomy, and give infinity a finite value. Do this and arithmetic is trivially proven to be self-contradictary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there a formal proof the fiction can't come true?

No, by [Gödel's second incompleteness theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems#Second_incompleteness_theorem), formal systems can prove their own consistency if and only if they are inconsistent. So given that arithmetic is consistent, we'll never be able to *prove* that it is. (**EDIT**: Actually not quite true; see Alon's clarification below.)

As an aside, if you liked "Division by Zero," you might also like Greg Egan's pair of stories in which arithmetic isn't consistent: "Luminous" and "[Dark Integers](http://www.asimovs.com/_issue_0805/DarkINtegers.shtml)".

Comment: Given that arithmetic is consistent, then *it* (arithmetic) cannot prove that it is. That doesn't mean that some other system can't achieve that feat. For instance, the consistency of Peano Arithmetic, which is a quite reasonable form of "Arithmetic", can be proved in ZFC, and much weaker systems as well.

Comment: Is this scenario possible: No matter if arithmetic is consistent or not, it can prove that a counterexample of its consistency can't be constructed, well, within itself (sorry if that doesn't make any sence, I mean, a counterexample will need more axioms).